# Why has the InstanceMethods module been deprecated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activesupport, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I love [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://www.fakingfantastic.com/2010/09/20/concerning-yourself-with-active-support-concern/).

It makes it easy to add functionality to your classes, with a nice syntax.

Anyways, in Rails 3.2, the InstanceMethods module has been deprecated. If I understood correctly, <strike>we should just define our methods in the `included` block</strike> (actually it's just in the body of the module):

```
# edit: don't do this! The method definition should just be in the body of the module
included do
    def my_method; end
end
```

I was just wondering if anyone knows why they decided to do that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Let's look at the example you linked first.

```
module TagLib
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def find_by_tags()
      # ...
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def tags()
      # ...
    end
  end 
end
```

When you include TagLib into your class AS Concern automatically extends the class with ClassMethods module and includes InstanceMethods module.

```
class Foo
  include TagLib
  # is roughly the same as
  include TagLib::InstanceMethods
  extend TagLib::ClassMethods
end
```

But as you may noticed we are already including TagLib module itself so the methods defined within it are already available as instance methods on the class. Why would you want to have a separate InstanceMethods module then?

```
module TagLib
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def find_by_tags()
      # ...
    end
  end

  def tags()
    # ...
  end
end

class Foo
  include TagLib
  # does only `extend TagLib::ClassMethods` for you
end
```

Comment: Ok, it makes sense. But now I'm wondering why they made this choice in the first place then... Is there NO differences between the way they included the InstanceMethods module and how normal instance methods of the module are included when I just do `include TagLib`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it just took some time to realize this.

Comment: Yeah, I think this was one of those times where they looked at the feature and said "WTF! Why did we do that?". Putting methods in the InstanceMethods module was superfluous. So no, there are no differences between the old way and the new way, just one less constant floating around.